# C# - can binary data be compiled into a module?

Tags: c#, binary-data

I want to include a large look-up table (100,000 of 3-byte values) inside a C# module.

Is there a compiler directive that will load binary data from an external file into a static string ?

Comment: Why not use an embedded resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just include the file into the assembly as an embedded resource, and then load it using [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx)? Then just load it from the stream into whatever in-memory data structure you want.